# How to send defaul text from FBPhotoParams

Tags: ios, facebook

I don't want to use open graph API due to their recent restrictions of submission of app for permissions, so I am using simple share dialog to share photo along with title:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
        clientState:nil
        handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Success!");
            }
 }];
```

But I want to add default text also in status. How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: I've been looking through the docs and to figure out how to do this - anyone have any luck?  It seems that the description property exists and is readonly.